# Can we have different distance for single source and destination?

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

On Monday, August 8, 2022 20:37:30(IST) and Sunday, August 14, 2022 17:02:32(IST), when we called Google Distance Matrix API for following source and destination address combination

**origin_addresses**: 143 River St, Jaffrey, NH 03452, USA

**destination_addresses**: 75 Lowell Rd, Salem, NH 03079, USA

We got different Response as following:

August 8, 2022 20:37:30- We got **101** km

August 14, 2022 17:02:32(IST) - We got **85.9** km

We don't have any extra query parameters except source an destination
**API URL**= [Google API URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=143%20River%20St,%20Jaffrey,%20NH%2003452,%20USA&destinations=75%20Lowell%20Rd,%20Salem,%20NH%2003079,%20USA)

1. Can we know, Is it possible to have different distance for single source and destination?

Comment: If you're using only one origin and one destination, what you should use is the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview). Distance Matrix API is for multiple origins/destinations request.

Comment: @Yrll I dont think it is mentioned any where , to not use distance API for single source and destination

Comment: @SolarMike both addresses are correct.

Comment: According to [Google Maps API picker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker)

You use Directions service for getting directions from origin to destination location using various forms of transport: walking, driving, cycling, public transit. Get a route from point A to point B.

For Distance Matrix it calculate the travel distance and travel time for multiple origins and destinations, optionally specifying various forms of transport: walking, driving, cycling.

Comment: Anyways, I tested your request on Directions API and the results gave me the same amount which is `62.7 miles` or `101 km`. I was wondering if the route changed in that area for the past few days? Here's the request I made: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=143%20River%20St,%20Jaffrey,%20NH%2003452,%20USA&destination=75%20Lowell%20Rd,%20Salem,%20NH%2003079,%20USA&key=MY_API_KEY

Comment: I guess the API also keeps track of the traffic on the route and gives you the fastest route

Comment: @Yrll Is there something sorting is applied in response? because it is array and has only one response but it is different, then it may be some sorting would have applied?

Comment: I'm currently drafting my answer because it can't fit here on the comment section. will be submitting it in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**. That is, if you are using Distance Matrix API. The API will only return a single route, which is the best possible route.

But it is possible to have different distance for a single origin and destination by including the `alternatives` parameter and setting it to `true` using [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview).

I commented on your question as to why it is recommended to use Directions API if you only have a single origin and a single destination. Or watch this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfj93TVbao0) for a quick explanation about Distance Matrix API and it's difference with Directions API.

With that said, I tried the address you used on the Directions API and included the parameter `alternatives` and set it to `true` and it showed an array of three alternate routes:

[image: Directions Result (alternate routes)]

Results are as follows:

Route #1

> distance: 101 km
> duration: 1 hour 20 mins

Route #2

> distance: 78.6 km
> duration: 1 hour 22 mins

Route #3

> distance: 85.9 km
> duration: 1 hour 20 mins

This concludes that the results you got on August 8 was the ***Route #1*** and the one from August 14 was the ***Route #3***.

The most probable cause of this could be the almost the same duration. although duration in hours is the same, if you look at the `value` on the results, route #1 had a `value: 4794` while route #3 had a `value: 4793`. And it could be interchanged because of traffic data and other factors, given that you had two different date and time on your requests(duration in traffic could be different on different days and different times of the day).

Here's what the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#:%7E:text=The%20API%20returns%20the%20most%20efficient%20routes%20when%20calculating%20directions.%20Travel%20time%20is%20the%20primary%20factor%20optimized%2C%20but%20the%20API%20may%20also%20take%20into%20account%20other%20factors%20such%20as%20distance%2C%20number%20of%20turns%20and%20many%20more%20when%20deciding%20which%20route%20is%20the%20most%20efficient.) says:

> *"The API returns the most efficient routes when calculating directions. Travel time is the primary factor optimized, but the API may also take into account other factors such as distance, number of turns and many more when deciding which route is the most efficient."*

Here's my request if you need some reference: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?units=metric&origin=143%20River%20St,%20Jaffrey,%20NH%2003452,%20USA&alternatives=true&destination=75%20Lowell%20Rd,%20Salem,%20NH%2003079,%20USA&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Just use your own API key and it should work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you just copy pasted my bug reported in google. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247469674#comment5

Comment: I have asked questions on last comments.

Comment: @SagarViradiya Yeap, I searched through the issue tracker after investigating your question and found out that you filed a bug report similar to this one so I answered.

Comment: If you confirm my questions

Comment: I'm willing to answer here if you need some more clarifications since your bug report would still be considered infeasible because the API was working as intended. And I provided more details here in my SO answer. That includes my sample request. I can't contain the full request results in a single png file so you should check it out yourself.

Comment: I just want answer in YES or NO for Distance Matrix API Only, If yes then how?

Comment: for your question #2, Distance Matrix API and Directions API works just the same with the difference that Directions API have the option to see alternate routes, while Distance Matrix gives you the best route/s only, but has the capability to return requests with multiple origins or destinations.

Comment: So NO, Distance Matrix only provides a single route, which is the best possible route when you put only a single origin and destination.

Comment: Ok, Thanks It will be helpful.

Comment: Can you please update answer. So it clearly states.

Comment: You could watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfj93TVbao0) if you want a quick explanation about Distance Matrix API.

Comment: I updated it, if you want me to edit more, please just comment it here. But if the answer satisfies you, you could mark it as accepted. The community would greatly appreciate it.